Rolling aggregation in polars and also get the original column back without join or using .over
Using polars .rolling and .agg, how do I get the original column back, without having to join back with the original column, or without having to use .over?
Example:
import polars as pl

dates = [
    "2020-01-01 13:45:48",
    "2020-01-01 16:42:13",
    "2020-01-01 16:45:09",
    "2020-01-02 18:12:48",
    "2020-01-03 19:45:32",
    "2020-01-08 23:16:43",
]
df = pl.DataFrame({"dt": dates, "a": [3, 7, 5, 9, 2, 1]}).with_columns(
    pl.col("dt").str.to_datetime().set_sorted()
)

Provides me with a small polars dataframe:
┌─────────────────────┬─────┐
│ dt                  ┆ a   │
│ ---                 ┆ --- │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64 │
╞═════════════════════╪═════╡
│ 2020-01-01 13:45:48 ┆ 3   │
│ 2020-01-01 16:42:13 ┆ 7   │
│ 2020-01-01 16:45:09 ┆ 5   │
│ 2020-01-02 18:12:48 ┆ 9   │
│ 2020-01-03 19:45:32 ┆ 2   │
│ 2020-01-08 23:16:43 ┆ 1   │
└─────────────────────┴─────┘

When I apply a rolling aggregations, I get the new columns back, but not the original columns:
out = df.rolling(index_column="dt", period="2d").agg(
    pl.sum("a").alias("sum_a"),
    pl.min("a").alias("min_a"),
    pl.max("a").alias("max_a"),
    pl.col("a")
)

which gives:
┌─────────────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ dt                  ┆ sum_a ┆ min_a ┆ max_a ┆ a            │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ list[i64]    │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ 2020-01-01 13:45:48 ┆ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ [3]          │
│ 2020-01-01 16:42:13 ┆ 10    ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ [3, 7]       │
│ 2020-01-01 16:45:09 ┆ 15    ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ [3, 7, 5]    │
│ 2020-01-02 18:12:48 ┆ 24    ┆ 3     ┆ 9     ┆ [3, 7, 5, 9] │
│ 2020-01-03 19:45:32 ┆ 11    ┆ 2     ┆ 9     ┆ [9, 2]       │
│ 2020-01-08 23:16:43 ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ [1]          │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴──────────────┘

How can I get the original a column. I don't want to join and I don't want to use .over as I need the group_by of the rolling later on and .over does not work with .rolling
Edit. I am also not keen on using the following.
out = df.rolling(index_column="dt", period="2d").agg(
    pl.sum("a").alias("sum_a"),
    pl.min("a").alias("min_a"),
    pl.max("a").alias("max_a"),
    pl.col("a").last()
)

Edit 2. Why Expr.rolling() is not feasible and why I need the group_by:
Given a more elaborate example:
dates = [
    "2020-01-01 13:45:48",
    "2020-01-01 16:42:13",
    "2020-01-01 16:45:09",
    "2020-01-02 18:12:48",
    "2020-01-03 19:45:32",
    "2020-01-08 23:16:43",
]
df_a = pl.DataFrame({"dt": dates, "a": [3, 7, 5, 9, 2, 1],"cat":["one"]*6}).with_columns(
    pl.col("dt").str.to_datetime()
)
df_b = pl.DataFrame({"dt": dates, "a": [3, 7, 5, 9, 2, 1],"cat":["two"]*6}).with_columns(
    pl.col("dt").str.to_datetime()
)

df = pl.concat([df_a,df_b])

┌─────────────────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ dt                  ┆ a   ┆ cat │
│ ---                 ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════════════════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 2020-01-01 13:45:48 ┆ 3   ┆ one │
│ 2020-01-01 16:42:13 ┆ 7   ┆ one │
│ 2020-01-01 16:45:09 ┆ 5   ┆ one │
│ 2020-01-02 18:12:48 ┆ 9   ┆ one │
│ 2020-01-03 19:45:32 ┆ 2   ┆ one │
│ 2020-01-08 23:16:43 ┆ 1   ┆ one │
│ 2020-01-01 13:45:48 ┆ 3   ┆ two │
│ 2020-01-01 16:42:13 ┆ 7   ┆ two │
│ 2020-01-01 16:45:09 ┆ 5   ┆ two │
│ 2020-01-02 18:12:48 ┆ 9   ┆ two │
│ 2020-01-03 19:45:32 ┆ 2   ┆ two │
│ 2020-01-08 23:16:43 ┆ 1   ┆ two │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴─────┘

and the code:
out = df.rolling(index_column="dt", period="2d",group_by="cat").agg(
    pl.sum("a").alias("sum_a"),
    pl.min("a").alias("min_a"),
    pl.max("a").alias("max_a"),
    pl.col("a")
)

┌─────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ cat ┆ dt                  ┆ sum_a ┆ min_a ┆ max_a ┆ a            │
│ --- ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ str ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ list[i64]    │
╞═════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ one ┆ 2020-01-01 13:45:48 ┆ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ [3]          │
│ one ┆ 2020-01-01 16:42:13 ┆ 10    ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ [3, 7]       │
│ one ┆ 2020-01-01 16:45:09 ┆ 15    ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ [3, 7, 5]    │
│ one ┆ 2020-01-02 18:12:48 ┆ 24    ┆ 3     ┆ 9     ┆ [3, 7, 5, 9] │
│ one ┆ 2020-01-03 19:45:32 ┆ 11    ┆ 2     ┆ 9     ┆ [9, 2]       │
│ one ┆ 2020-01-08 23:16:43 ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ [1]          │
│ two ┆ 2020-01-01 13:45:48 ┆ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ [3]          │
│ two ┆ 2020-01-01 16:42:13 ┆ 10    ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ [3, 7]       │
│ two ┆ 2020-01-01 16:45:09 ┆ 15    ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ [3, 7, 5]    │
│ two ┆ 2020-01-02 18:12:48 ┆ 24    ┆ 3     ┆ 9     ┆ [3, 7, 5, 9] │
│ two ┆ 2020-01-03 19:45:32 ┆ 11    ┆ 2     ┆ 9     ┆ [9, 2]       │
│ two ┆ 2020-01-08 23:16:43 ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ [1]          │
└─────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴──────────────┘

This does not work:
df.sort("dt").with_columns(sum=pl.sum("a").rolling(index_column="dt", period="2d").over("cat"))

Gives:
# InvalidOperationError: rolling expression not allowed in aggregation


What speaks against using pl.col("a").last()? This seems idiomatic to me.

I find it odd that I have to do another operation (.last) to get something I already had at the beginning. I would assume there is some way to do a pl.exclude() or something ...

Then why is there an issue to join?

You could use pl.exclude("cols", "to", "exclude").last() to keep all columns that are not excluded. This behaviour is in line with pl.DataFrame.group_by().agg() as only index columns and columns explicitly mentioned in the aggregation are kept.

@mozway Same argument: Why should I add something that I had at the start? For example, if you are using scikit-learn's ColumnTransformer, you can define what should be passed through. It feels counterintuitive that you can't just let the original column pass through IMO.

There are dedicated rolling_*_by expressions e.g. pl.col("a").rolling_sum_by("dt", "2d").alias("sum_a")

There are dedicated rolling_*_by expressions which can be used with .over()
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("a").rolling_sum_by("dt", "2d").over("cat").name.prefix("sum_"),
    pl.col("a").rolling_min_by("dt", "2d").over("cat").name.prefix("min_"),
    pl.col("a").rolling_max_by("dt", "2d").over("cat").name.prefix("max_")
)

shape: (12, 6)
┌─────────────────────┬─────┬─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ dt                  ┆ a   ┆ cat ┆ sum_a ┆ min_a ┆ max_a │
│ ---                 ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64 ┆ str ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-01-01 13:45:48 ┆ 3   ┆ one ┆ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ 3     │
│ 2020-01-01 16:42:13 ┆ 7   ┆ one ┆ 10    ┆ 3     ┆ 7     │
│ 2020-01-01 16:45:09 ┆ 5   ┆ one ┆ 15    ┆ 3     ┆ 7     │
│ 2020-01-02 18:12:48 ┆ 9   ┆ one ┆ 24    ┆ 3     ┆ 9     │
│ 2020-01-03 19:45:32 ┆ 2   ┆ one ┆ 11    ┆ 2     ┆ 9     │
│ …                   ┆ …   ┆ …   ┆ …     ┆ …     ┆ …     │
│ 2020-01-01 16:42:13 ┆ 7   ┆ two ┆ 10    ┆ 3     ┆ 7     │
│ 2020-01-01 16:45:09 ┆ 5   ┆ two ┆ 15    ┆ 3     ┆ 7     │
│ 2020-01-02 18:12:48 ┆ 9   ┆ two ┆ 24    ┆ 3     ┆ 9     │
│ 2020-01-03 19:45:32 ┆ 2   ┆ two ┆ 11    ┆ 2     ┆ 9     │
│ 2020-01-08 23:16:43 ┆ 1   ┆ two ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴─────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘


I am using Polar 20.23, and it seems this does not exist. Which version are you using?

@Olivier_s_j I'm using 0.20.31

@Olivier_s_j .rolling_sum("2d", by="dt").over("cat") may work on older versions - not entirely sure.

You can use Expr.rolling() instead:
aggs = [(pl.min, '_min'), (pl.max, '_max'), (pl.sum, '_sum')]

df.with_columns(
    cfunc('a').rolling('dt', period='2d').name.suffix(csuf) for cfunc, csuf in aggs
)

┌─────────────────────┬─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ dt                  ┆ a   ┆ a_min ┆ a_max ┆ a_sum │
│ ---                 ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-01-01 13:45:48 ┆ 3   ┆ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ 3     │
│ 2020-01-01 16:42:13 ┆ 7   ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ 10    │
│ 2020-01-01 16:45:09 ┆ 5   ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ 15    │
│ 2020-01-02 18:12:48 ┆ 9   ┆ 3     ┆ 9     ┆ 24    │
│ 2020-01-03 19:45:32 ┆ 2   ┆ 2     ┆ 9     ┆ 11    │
│ 2020-01-08 23:16:43 ┆ 1   ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘

Edit:
I think what you need is to use rolling(...).over(...), but unfortunately it seems to be unsupported yet.
There's a open request for it though.
If you can live with using last() I'd do that for now.

I need the group_by of the Dataframe.rolling() as .over does not work with the Expr.rolling()

It would've been easier then if you would've extended your example to show why proposed solutions (and your original one) do not work

Ok, I extended the example.

You can do
In [9]: df.with_columns(
   ...:     a_min=pl.col('a').min().rolling('dt', period='2d'),
   ...:     a_max=pl.col('a').max().rolling('dt', period='2d'),
   ...:     a_sum=pl.col('a').sum().rolling('dt', period='2d'),
   ...: )
shape: (6, 5)
┌─────────────────────┬─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ dt                  ┆ a   ┆ a_min ┆ a_max ┆ a_sum │
│ ---                 ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-01-01 13:45:48 ┆ 3   ┆ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ 3     │
│ 2020-01-01 16:42:13 ┆ 7   ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ 10    │
│ 2020-01-01 16:45:09 ┆ 5   ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ 15    │
│ 2020-01-02 18:12:48 ┆ 9   ┆ 3     ┆ 9     ┆ 24    │
│ 2020-01-03 19:45:32 ┆ 2   ┆ 2     ┆ 9     ┆ 11    │
│ 2020-01-08 23:16:43 ┆ 1   ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘

Alternatively (and probably more efficient):
In [16]: df.with_columns(
    ...:     a_min=pl.col('a').rolling_min_by('dt', '2d'),
    ...:     a_max=pl.col('a').rolling_max_by('dt', '2d'),
    ...:     a_sum=pl.col('a').rolling_sum_by('dt', '2d'),
    ...: )
Out[16]:
shape: (6, 5)
┌─────────────────────┬─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ dt                  ┆ a   ┆ a_min ┆ a_max ┆ a_sum │
│ ---                 ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-01-01 13:45:48 ┆ 3   ┆ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ 3     │
│ 2020-01-01 16:42:13 ┆ 7   ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ 10    │
│ 2020-01-01 16:45:09 ┆ 5   ┆ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ 15    │
│ 2020-01-02 18:12:48 ┆ 9   ┆ 3     ┆ 9     ┆ 24    │
│ 2020-01-03 19:45:32 ┆ 2   ┆ 2     ┆ 9     ┆ 11    │
│ 2020-01-08 23:16:43 ┆ 1   ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘


this uses the .rolling expression, which does not have the group_by, which I need (for the actual code, not this simple example).
